# How to fix undefined method `name' for #<Contact id: nil>?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd love to get help on this as I cannot figure out the answer. I'm getting an error message that says

```
undefined method `name' for #<Contact id: nil>
```

and I have no idea what's wrong.

My view file looks like this

```
<div class="container">
```

Contact Us

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
  <%= flash[:notice] %>
  <div class="well">
    <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
```

that's not all of it but the problem line seems to be

```
<%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
```

even though I didn't touch that line.

What I changed was

```
<%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
```

from

```
<%= form_for "/contacts" do |f| %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
This is my contacts_controller

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params) 
    if @contact.save
      redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Message Sent."
    else 
      redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Error occured"
    end
  end

  private 
    def contact_params
      params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments)
    end
end
```

EDIT 2:
I figured it out, but I'm not too sure why it works. If someone can explain it to me I would really appreciate it. I ran `rails db:reset`, `rails db:drop`, and `rails db:migrate` in my console and that seemed to fix the problem. I recall when I was initially typing `rails db:migrate` I accidentally typed in `rails db migrate` instead. Could that be the cause of the problem?

Comment: It's the Contact object which hasn't been saved or created yet. It has no id and obviously has no name. So could you please add the whole output with error so we can find out where exactly you can find it?

Comment: why did you change @contact to "/contact" ?

Comment: I added an edit, but I'm not too sure if that's what you were asking for.

Comment: @Rockwell Rice
I'm going through a video course called Upskill Courses, and the instructor told me to change it to '@contact'. The instructor said it's because "/contact" was a placeholder to '@contact', so that it could be associated with the contacts_controller page.

Comment: From your last edit, it appears as if your `Contact` model didn't have a `name` attribute for some reason. When you dropped and re-migrated, the database caught up

Answer (score 1):

According to your last Edit, yes `rails db migrate` could cause this problem because when you run it you may not noticed that it failed and not created the column for `name` for `Contact` model and though you can't access it, and if you run it correctly without destroying the db and creating again that would work, because only your last migrations weren't run, and as a future reference to know what is the last migration run is by check `schema.rb` you will see in the top the migration id which is the first part of the migration name (timestamp).